# SharePoint Release Management Testing and Roll back

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, restore, testing

I'm putting together a release process for our SharePoint 2007 environment. We have admins and power users who have to make out of the box changes to sites via the browser. Only one admin who can make some custom authored Workflows in SharePoint Designer 2007. Both admins and also a few power users who will soon author and publish InfoPath 2007 to both TEST and LIVE (they're currently in training). The Development team can also create custom WSPs. So from above we three types of change

1. Out of the Box
2. SharePoint Designer and InfoPath
3. WSPs

We get a lot of request for changes mostly for new sites with libraries and list (some with custom workflows) and also using content types, content roll ups using the Content Query Web Part and the summary links web parts.

Basically we don't want overkill on perhaps the out of the box changes. But I'd be interested knowing what tests plans and rollback steps others are using for their release process for each of the above senarios

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I came across this link on website. This may help: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/sharepoint-2010-release-management.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage